# Is there any theoretical calculation for the nuclear magnetic moment for beryllium-7?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Magnetic moment measured for Be7 is -1,39.
Is there a theoretical calculation which aproaches to this experimental value?

I did not find any in the internet.

Answer (score 3):

[M. E. Rose and H. A. Bethe, Phys. Rev. 51, 205 (1937)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.51.205).
Their theoretical value is -1.30. From the abstract: "From the results of Feenberg and Wigner for the wave function and term character of the ground state of light nuclei (mass number between 6 and 16), the nuclear spins are determined."